# Is there a way to find out which task is currently running in SSIS when running in SQL Server Agent job?

Tags: ssis

When I have to tell my boss how long it will take to finish the current SSIS package, I can get an estimate when the job is running in Visual Studio environment, but I'm totally blind when it's running using SQL Server Agent.

Is there any way to find out where the SSIS package is at a certain moment or which task is currently running at a certain moment?

Comment: Under sql server agent in ssms there is a job activity monitor which displays the job status and other job related information

Comment: Yeah I know about it, I want to know, which task is currently running in an specific SSIS Task.

Comment: I think I need to create some log tables against each task. May be there is some better approach.

Comment: Use SSIS Logging feature and select sql server  as provider type .Then you can query this table and get to know details such as which package is currently executing which task got failed ,timestamp and many more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating your own log tables recording the steps that you are interested in works well if you are using SQL 2008 R2 (or earlier).

SQL 2012 has created a logging framework for you that will tell a host of information including the completed control flow steps.  Within SSMS, look under Integration Services Catalogs and find your package.  Right click and look under the Reports tab to get a detailed breakdown of past and current SSIS executions

Comment: I believe it shows you only completed tasks not the currently running ones.

Comment: Same problem. It only tells you what is currently completed and not what is running. Guess logging it is!

Answer (score -1):

SQL 2014 shows running jobs in Service Catalog.

[image: Example image]